# Wordpress: Disable update mail when changing email of user

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

So I have a custom post type called: members. linked with ACF. And when I add/edit a member in the post type it also changes the corresponding account in WordPress users.

So when I edit the account inside the post type, I get a mail confirming the mail change. I need this automated mail to be disabled. for the old mail and the new mail

So how do I disable this mail?

Comment: why not to use custom attribute 'email' of member post type?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you as **admin** receive the update by email or you as **user** (simulating a member)?

And are you using a plugin to send the user email change email, because I don't think this is a native WordPress behaviour? Look for an add_action for 'profile_update', for example:

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'profile_update_notification', 10, 2 );
```